# inline login form image not display full

Tags: html, css

HTML :

```css
form {
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
form img {
  width: 75px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
form input {
  padding: 12px 17px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 155px;
  color: #fff;
}
form button,
#btnDaftar,
#btnLivechat {
  display: inline-block; background: url(http://jawapoker88.com/img/images/login.png) top left no-repeat; width: 110px; height: 25px; border: none; cursor: pointer;}
  #btnDaftar {
    background-image: url(http://jawapoker88.com/img/images/daftar.png)
  }
  form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
  }
  form input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff
  }
  form input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #fff
  }
  form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="SITELOGIN" method="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="SITELOGIN" method="password" />
    <button type="submit" class="SITELOGIN" method="login"></button>
    <a href="#" id="btnDaftar" class="SITELOGIN" method="register"></a>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS

Question : how to display a full image of login button and daftar button?

Here's what it looks like at the moment:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Could you explain why you rolled back the edit I made? My edit made the question easier to read, and easier to answer(because of the snippet). I'd just like to know what you didn't like about the edit, and your causes for removing it.

Comment: im sorry, just wanted to edit the height, from 25 to 31px, im new on here sir, how to use code snipped?

Comment: Snippets allow people to run/test your code easily, and they provide a basic code editor. To edit a snippet, you can simply edit the code in the answer, or go to the preview and click "edit this snippet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the easiest thing to do, without setting a height to the buttons, is to just use an `img` element:

```css
form {
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
form input {
  padding: 12px 17px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 155px;
  color: #fff;
}
form button,
#btnDaftar,
#btnLivechat {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background:transparent;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
form input:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff
}
form input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #fff
}
form input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <form method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" class="SITELOGIN" method="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" class="SITELOGIN" method="password" />
    <button type="submit" class="SITELOGIN" method="login">
      <img src="http://jawapoker88.com/img/images/login.png">
    </button>
    <a href="#" id="btnDaftar" class="SITELOGIN" method="register">
      <img src="http://jawapoker88.com/img/images/daftar.png">
    </a>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `background-size: contain` to `#header form button, #btnDaftar, #btnLivechat` to let the image fit the container. For a prettier end-result, you could also add `vertical-align: middle;` to make it align right.

Comment: tried to use background-size: contain but didnt work